# Whenever I save any Node, I lose the ability to edit it?

Tags: users

1. Browse to Node Edit Page, ex. /node/44/edit
2. Click Save
3. Browse back to node edit page, it says "Access Denied"

Runnning drupal 7.16

and these modules:
addressfield      commerce_migrate_ubercart    emfield             jplayer         page_title     tap
admin_menu        commerce_moa                 entity              jquery_update   pathauto       taxonomy_menu
browscap          commerce_node_checkout       entityreference     libraries       phone          title
calendar          commerce_product_attributes  entity_translation  media           README.txt     token
calendar_block    commerce_shipping            fb_social           media_flickr    redirect       transliteration
captcha           commerce_views_display       features            media_youtube   references     tumblr_connect
cck               constant_contact             field_collection    menu_block      rules          views
ckeditor          contact_form_blocks          flickr              metatag         securepages    webform
cnr               ctools                       fp                  migrate         simplehtmldom  wysiwyg
commerce          date                         geofield            migrate_extras  site_map       wysiwyg_filter
commerce_authnet  devel                        geophp              mollom          strongarm
commerce_coupon   devel_themer                 google_analytics    nodehierarchy   styles
commerce_migrate  email                        interval            openlayers      superfish

This is so confusing, becuase I cant think of what I changed that would cause this.

This project is a drupal 6 to 7 upgrade with a switch from ubercart to commerce

Any help greatly appreciated and my head will thank u

Comment: Try this: become the Drupal administrator. Do you still get the same permission problem? I assume you looked at the obvious of checking ALL permissions?

Comment: Yes the account is (user id 1 account) set as drupal administrator, i tried setting permissions for everything site administrator and tried to rebuild the node permissions, no joy.  ANy ideas?

Comment: Does this only affect a particular content type?  Or it affects ALL content types?

Comment: So far, all content types, i have checked, Page, Product, Blog Entry

Comment: I know this is painful, but try disabling modules one-by-one to see if you can identify the culprit module.

Comment: That found it ! Its the Entity Translation module, checking permissions on that revealed all permissions have been set for Site Administrator though

Comment: This is what I would try to do: BACKUP any tables related to Entity Translation in the MySQL database.  BACK it up.  Or just backup the entire DB to be extra safe!  Now, after you have disabled the entity translation module, UNINSTALL it in Drupal.  This will DELETE and remove any saved information from Entity Translation.  Then, reenable the module and re-configure it and/or rebuild permissions.  Does this fix the problem?  You are using an alpha module.  Perhaps it is a known bug? Did you check the module's issue list?  Maybe others have the same problem?  You might want to report it to them